# Pagination not displaying correct number of pages

Tags: custom-field, loop, pagination

I have been working on a shortcode to query pages by category and display custom fields.  I have everything working great except; if my 'custom_field' variable is "numeric", it returns the correct number of 'posts_per_page', if my 'custom_field' variable is "text", it doesn't return anything unless the 'posts_per_page' is entered in multiples of 10.  For example, if I want to show '5' posts, I have to enter 'posts_per_page="50".

I am completely baffled.

On a different note, I have been reading that I should not use "extract(shortcode_atts("  but I am not able to pass my variables without doing it this way.  How should this be written?

As always, I really appreciate your guidance.

// Begin Shortcode

```
add_shortcode("custom_query_test_100", "custom_query_test_100");

function custom_query_test_100($atts, $content = null) {

    // Attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'pagination' => 'true',
            'query' => '',
            'category' => '',
            'custom_field' => '',
            'number_posts' => '',
            'order_by'   => '',
            'order'     => '',      
        ), $atts ));


    // WP_Query arguments
    $args = array(
        'paged'                  => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ),
        'post_type'              => array( 'page', ' post' ),
        'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
        'cat'                    => $category,
        'meta_key'               => $custom_field,
        'posts_per_page'         => '50',
        'order'                  => $order,
        'orderby'                => $order_by,
        );

    // The Query
    global $wp_query,$paged,$post;
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    ob_start(); 

    if ($query->have_posts()):
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

    if ( strlen(get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_field, true)) > 0 ) :
    ?>

    <div style="margin:10px 0 30px;"></div>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
        <h2 style="margin:0 0 5px 0; font-size:24px;"><?php echo the_title(); ?></h2>       
        <div class="one-third-width-responsive">        
        <?php echo the_post_thumbnail( 'large' );  ?>       
        </div>
        </a>

        <div class="two-third-width-responsive">        
        <div style="font-size:15px;"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_field, true); ?></div>
        </div>

        <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <?php 
    endwhile;     
    endif;
    ?>

    <div style="margin-top:35px;"></div>

    <?php if ($query->max_num_pages > 1) : // custom pagination  ?>
        <?php
        $orig_query = $wp_query; // fix for pagination to work
        $wp_query = $query;
        ?>

        <div style="margin:20px 0; background-color:#e3f0f7; width:100%; padding:30px;">
            <div style="float:left; line-height:0;"><?php echo get_previous_posts_link('« Previous'); ?></div>
            <div style="float:right; line-height:0;"><?php echo get_next_posts_link('Next »', $query->max_num_pages ); ?></div>
        </div>

       <?php
        $wp_query = $orig_query; // fix for pagination to work

        endif;      

    wp_reset_postdata();    

    $output = ob_get_clean();
    //print $output; // debug
    return $output; 

}
```

// End

Answer (score -1):

You follow this link:https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links i hope your problem solve.